# Get jQuery to work on element added to the DOM

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function:

```
   $(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth
    if (width > 769) {
            $("#slideshowgrande").load('/slideshow.php')            
    }
})
```

That adds a piece of code (a slideshow, in this case) to the DOM.
Unfortunately jQuery does't work on this slideshow because it was added to the DOM separately. 
How can I tell jQuery to work on that element that's been added?

Comment: you need load completed event right?

Comment: The fact that I'm seeing the whole slideshow. The slideshow is there. SO it was added. But it's frozen. It doesn't work because it was added to the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete callback of `load()` to run code associated with the new html

```
$("#slideshowgrande").load('/slideshow.php', function(){
     /* new html now exists , run your code here*/
});
```

Reference: [load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: So I have to add all the function related to my slideshow in that piece of code?

Comment: you can access the elements there via `this` which you either work with within this function, or call another function where your slideshow handling code is located

Comment: Yes, you could wrap it in a function like `slideShowInit()` or something similar and call the function inside callback